# Quantum Cohomology of fiber products

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, quantum-cohomology

It is well known that the (small) quantum cohomology of a product of two varieties $X$ and $Y$ is given by the tensor product 
\begin{equation}QH^\bullet(X)\otimes QH^\bullet(Y).
\end{equation}
This is a quantum analogue of the Künneth Theorem. Is it known any general result about more general fiber products? In other words, given $X\to Y$ and $Z\to Y$, are there any results which relate $QH^\bullet(X\times_Y Z)$ with $QH^\bullet(X), QH^\bullet(Y), QH^\bullet(Z)$?

Is there any hope for some quantum analogue of Eilenberg-Moore Spectral sequences?